# How to set the font style for a webpage in one place without being overridden by user agent stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use CSS in one place to specify the font-style everywhere on my web page. I tried the following:

```
  body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #dfeff0;}
```

I have several forms on the webpage with some default input text. I noticed that the style of the input text in the forms was being overridden by the user agent stylesheet. This makes sense since the default CSS for the text input box is more specific than the CSS that I specified for my body element. I can change the text in the input box to my preferred style by writing another line of CSS that specifically targets the input box, however, this seems like bad practice as it violates the DRY principle. As my webpage gets larger I imagine that I will have the same text style rule written in many places as I continue to "fight" with the default CSS.

Is there a way to write CSS code that is both general (applied to all elements) and immune to being overridden by the more specific default CSS? What are the best practices for the situation I am describing.

Here is the form i'm referring to just in case its relevant.

```
<form action="" method="">
      <input id="task-field" type="text" name="task_contents" value="... (enter a task)">
      <input id="start" type="text" name="start_time" value="Start Time">
      <input id="duration" type="text" name="task_duration" value="Duration">
      <label for="all_day_task">All Day Task</label>
      <input id="all-day" type="checkbox" name="all_day_task">
      <label for="all_day_task">All Day Task</label>
      <input id="long-term" type="checkbox" name="long_term_task">
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `* { font-family: inherit; }`? Your `body` ruleset in your example won't be overridden since `*` has `0` specificity. You can also do `input { font: inherit; }` to get the font family and size to be consistent.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Advanced_form_styling "Applying the following CSS to them removes system-level styling.: `input {-webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none;}`"

Answer (score 1):

u can use * tag to make all elements

```
 * {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif ;

}
```